# write csv files including unicode with python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, unicode

I am writing a large list that includes some non-ascii characters into a csv file using the `csv` module. I keep getting the following error message

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 48-50: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I don't need those characters so it's ok to ignore them. I tried different ways recommended on SOF but none of them worked so far (the error message is the same). Is there an easy way to get around the encoding error and proceed? I tried:

```
io.open(file, encoding = "utf-8")
codecs.open(file, encoding = "utf-8")
codes.open(file, errors = "ignore")
```

I can write the data into csv using the `pandas` module by simply setting `encoding = "utf-8"`. Can I do something similar in `csv` module?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Python 2.7 you should use the `unicodecsv` module: [unicodecsv 0.9.4](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/unicodecsv/0.9.4). This is a replacement for Python's built-in `csv` module and it does support Unicode. In Python 3.x you no longer need this replacement as Python 3.x does support Unicode in its `csv` module.

You can install it by running:

```
pip install unicodecsv
```

Answer (score 0):

You can install **[unicodecsv](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/unicodecsv/0.9.4)** or you can write your row in **utf-8** format while writing in your `CSV` file using `csv writer`.

```
import csv
with open("sample.csv", "w") as wf:
    writer = csv.writer(wf)
    writer.writerow([unicode(s, "utf-8") for s in row])
```